# Send one email per unique value

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I created code to generate emails using values from one column, copy a table into the email body and send it to the email address from another column.

When I have multiple rows of data connected to the same person, the code is generating multiple emails to this person, including the same data/table in body.

How do I skip duplicated email addresses, and only send one per person?

```vb
Sub Emails()
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Setting parameters
    Dim EApp As Object
    Set EApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim EItem As Object
    
    Dim I As Long
    Dim Rec As String
    Dim DateStart As Date
    
    Dim MailWb As Workbook
    Dim MListSheet As Worksheet
    Dim MListTable As ListObject
    Set MListSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")
    Set MListTable = MListSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    
    'Setting Agent for signature purposes
    Dim Agent$
    Agent = InputBox("Insert your name and surname")
    
    'Generating body of the e-mail
    For I = 2 To MListTable.ListRows.Count + 1
        Rec = MListTable.Range(I, MListTable.ListColumns("Manager").Index)
        MListTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=MListTable.ListColumns("Manager").Index, Field:=1, Criteria1:=Rec
    
        If MListTable.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row > 1 Then
            Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(0)
            With EItem
                .To = MListTable.Range(I, MListTable.ListColumns("Mail").Index)
                .CC = ""
                .Subject = "XXXX" & " " & Format(Now(), "mm/yyyy")
                .HTMLBody = "XXXX" _
                & "<br><br>" & "XXXX" _
                & RangetoHTML(MListTable.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) _
                & "<br>" & "BR," _
                & "<br>" & Agent
                .Display
            End With
        
        End If
        MListTable.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        
        Next I
        
    Set EApp = Nothing
    Set EItem = Nothing
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Using a dictionary sounds exactly what you'd need here. Try putting a check right after `Rec =` if it exists in your (newly added to the code) [dictionary](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) and add the Rec to your dictionary if it doesn't exist and only then send the mail. If it already exists, you'll go to the next I-iteration. Hope I didn't misunderstand your code/question.

Comment: Hi Notus_Panda! Thank you for your suggestion, however I am not sure if I used the dictionary code correctly (never tried it before). Seems like right now it is not generating emails at all. The value exists but in several rows, so I need the code to generate only 1 email per unique value, and if the value is >1, skip the rest and go to the next i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing example data, this is what your for-loop could look like:

```
'Generating body of the e-mail
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For I = 2 To MListTable.ListRows.Count + 1
    Rec = MListTable.Range(I, MListTable.ListColumns("Przelozony").Index)
    If Not dict.Exists(Rec) Then
        MListTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=MListTable.ListColumns("Przelozony").Index, Field:=1, Criteria1:=Rec
    
        If MListTable.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row > 1 Then
            Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(0)
            With EItem
                .To = MListTable.Range(I, MListTable.ListColumns("Mail").Index)
                .CC = ""
                .Subject = "Przekroczenie dobowe" & " " & Format(Now(), "mm/yyyy")
                .HTMLBody = "Witam," & "<br><br>" & "Ponizej przesylam przekroczenia 12 godzin pracy na dobe. Prosze o pilne wyjasnienie sytuacji oraz podanie dzialan, jakie zostana podjete w celu unikniecia takich sytuacji w przyszlosci." _
                & "<br><br>" & "I am submitting below the exceedances of 12 hours of work per day. Please urgently explain the situation and provide what actions will be taken to avoid such situations in the future." _
                & RangetoHTML(MListTable.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) _
                & "<br>" & "Pozdrawiam/Best regards" _
                & "<br>" & Agent
                .display
            End With
        
        End If
        MListTable.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        dict.Add Rec, ""
    End If
Next I
```

If there are duplicates from the visible cells after the Autofilter, you could use a temporary sheet to paste the found values and get the unique values in a separate dictionary from there and then use its keys.